# $f(x)-f(y) \le (x-y)^2 $. Prove that $f(x)-f(y) \leq \frac{(x-y)^2}{n}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ bea function such that $f(x)-f(y) \le (x-y)^2$, $\forall~ x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ . For a given $n \in \mathbb{N}$, prove that $f(x)-f(y) \leq \frac{(x-y)^2}{n}$  $\forall~ x,y \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Is it $1\over n(x-y)^2$ or $(x-y)^2\over n$?

Comment: Split up the interval $[x,y]$ into $n$ equal subintervals.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I highly suspect that this is the solution they had in mind... But if one uses Analysis, one can immediately prove that $f$ is constant, which can also be proven by your suggested approach :)

Comment: What efforts have you made to solve it? Can you show that this function is differentiable?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

First note that interchanging $x,y$ you can deduce that

$$|f(x)-f(y)| \leq (x-y)^2$$
Then, for each $x \neq y$ you have
$$\left| \frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y} \right| \leq |x-y|$$

Deduce from here that $f$ is differentiable everywhere and $f'(x)=0 \forall x$

Answer (score 1):

Divide the gap from $x$ to $y$ into $n$ equal pieces, then finish with the triangle inequality.